# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie in OnAuthorization of custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, forms-authentication

I am trying to set an auth cookie in OnAuthorization of my custom attribute in asp.net mvc(C#) application.

when the session expires(New Session), i am setting an auth cookie again to make it available until the users logout.

I have used the following to set the auth cookie,

```
//set forms auth cookie
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(strUserName, true);
```

But when i check `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, it returns false.

How to set an auth cookie in OnAuthorization of custom attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the auth cookie, you won't automatically get `Context.User` filled in, you need to do something like:

```
Context.User = new GenericPrincipal (new GenericIdentity (strUserName, "Forms"), null);
```

where *strUserName* must be non-null and not empty for `IsAuthenticated` to return *true*.
On the next request, `Context.User` should be set by the `FormsAuthenticationModule` and you won't have to do anything.

Comment: I Used it, It works for the current request. But when for next page/ other request. The request is not authenticated. Can u please help me over here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that you might need to redirect to a new page after you set the auth cookie and then on the new page check the IsAuthenticated. I don't completely remember the order this happens in but this reminds me of an issue I've had.